# Fill a Cell in Excel depending on the result from another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft

I need to fill column E with the data entered in column B, this is dependent on Column D matching to Colum A. See below it works for the first row, but the second one is wrong. When I get to row 3 it fails as well as there is no result in cell B3.

The data will have one occurrence of the postcode in column A, but multiple occurrences in column D

Formula I have tried so far is: `=IF(MATCH(D1,A:A,0),B1)`

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SO21 3LF | Sainsburys |  | SO21 3LF | Sainsburys |
| SO22 2JK | Asda |  | SO21 3LF | Asda |
|  |  |  | SO21 3LF |  |
|  |  |  | SO22 2JK |  |
|  |  |  | SO22 2JK |  |
|  |  |  | SO21 3LF |  |

[image]

Comment: [Please post your data as text, not image.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/372239)

Comment: What about `IF(D1=A1,B1,"")`? What formula have you tried?

Comment: That works, but only if the postcodes line up on the same row. The problem is i will only have one occurance of the postcode in Column A, but multiple occurances in column D. Formula i tried was: IF(MATCH(D1,A:A,0),B1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following formula:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$2,MATCH(D1,$A$1:$A$2,0))
```

Adapt the formula to your data. Drag down to fill the other cells.

[image]

Comment: Perfect, that has done the job, much appreciated.

Comment: @LukeB See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers).